# Strategies for fast integrity attestation over multi party computation for large messages

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation, integrity

I am looking for ways to efficiently perform integrity attestation over large messages using multi party computation. While, hashing (SHA1, 256...) is one alternative but it's painfully slow and grows linearly in length of the message.

Comment: what did you do in the end?

Comment: Some solutions in the literature they use a checksum. Well, the only thing that I can think of that makes them go for a checksum, not a cryptographic function is the speed of computation.